# How to dynamic_cast a variadic template with mismatch reference modifier in parameters?

Tags: c++, c++11, variadic-templates, dynamic-cast, perfect-forwarding

I have a class hierarchy where the base class contains a function which tests for `dynamic_cast` the `this` pointer into a derived template type based on the arguments it receive.

Problem is that `dynamic_cast` operator checks for exact match of the arguments, taking into account if they are ref or not. I need the following example to work on both cases, is there a way to do so?

```
template <typename... P>
struct Derived;

struct Base
{
    virtual ~Base() {}

    template <typename... P>
    void doCast(P&&... p) {
        Derived<P...> *res=dynamic_cast<Derived<P...> *>(this);
        if (!res)
            std::cout<<"Failed."<<std::endl;
        else {
            std::cout<<"Success."<<std::endl;
            res->doSomethingWithP(std::forward<P>(p)...);
        }
    }
};

template <typename... P>
struct Derived: public Base
{
    void doSomethingWithP(P... p) {
        /*Whatever, doesn't matter*/
    }
};

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    Derived<int, int, int> derived;
    Base *b=&derived;

    int x=10;
    int y=20;
    int z=30;

    //The two calls must succeed.
    b->doCast(x,y,z); //Failed.
    b->doCast(10,20,30); //Success.

    return 0;
}
```

`Derived` can accept types that are both values, references, and pointers - *cv*-qualified or not.

Comment: To be clear - will you actually also instantiate `Derived<int, int&>`? What should `b->doCast(10, 20);` do in such case?

Comment: Or really, what should `b->doCast(x);` do if both `Derived<int>` and `Derived<int&>` are possible?

Comment: Ok, so they can be references to const. Same question stands, `Derived<int>` or `Derived<int const&>`?

Comment: If `this` class is `int` or `const int &` it should do both castings fine.

Comment: @LoPiTaL So you want it do, potentially `2^N` different casts?

Comment: @Barry No, I want the expression to succeed whether it receives a reference or not. I have simplified the description of the problem, and once this basic case is working, we will discuss other more complex types.

Comment: @LoPiTaL Well if `Derived` doesn't take references, just have `doCast` not take references.

Comment: @Barry Ok, without references it works fine. Just removing the && of the doCast parameters and it dynamic_cast'ed fine. Now, lets go back again to the const & case, where I can receive a reference

Comment: @LoPiTaL You're not understanding the issue. Let's say `doCast` gets called with 5 arguments of types `A`, `B`, ..., `E`. That means we'd have to potentially check against {`A`, `A const&`} x {`B`, `B const&`} x {`C`, `C const&`} x ... That's 32 potential `Derived` types!

Comment: Ok, I see the problem. Then I guess that my best shot is to go without references, and pay a little performance penalty. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just moving my comments to an answer. In the typical case, if both `Derived<int>` and `Derived<int const&>` are allowed as types, `Base::doCast` would have to perform potentially two different casts per argument type, or `2^N` total casts. This is unfeasible.

However, what you can do instead is (1) require that `Derived`'s template arguments not be references and (2) have it take its arguments by reference. So we just remove the references on all of the `P`s:

```
template <typename... P>
void doCast(P&&... p) {
    if (auto res = dynamic_cast<Derived<std::remove_reference_t<P>...>*>(this)) {
        std::cout << "Success." << std::endl;
        res->doSomethingWithP(p...); // NOT forward
    }
    else {
        std::cout << "Failed." << std::endl;
    }
}
```

And take by reference on the other side so that we don't incur the extra copy:

```
template <typename... P>
struct Derived: public Base
{
    void doSomethingWithP(P&... ) {
        /*Whatever, doesn't matter*/
    }
};
```

However, this still lets us make `Derived<int&>`, which will *never* work in this model. So let's explicitly disallow that. First some boilerplate:

```
template<bool...> struct bool_pack;

template<bool f, bool... bs> 
using all_same = std::is_same<bool_pack<bs..., f>, bool_pack<f, bs...>>;

template <bool... bs>
using none = all_same<false, bs...>;
```

Then:

```
template <typename... P>
struct Derived: public Base
{
    static_assert(none<std::is_reference<P>::value...>::value, 
                  "Can't make Derived with references");
    ...
};
```

Comment: It works like a charm! Thank you very much! Just a side note, since I am not using c++14, I cannot use the type `std::remove_reference_t`, so in order to get the typename correct, the definition should be as follows: `Derived<typename std::remove_reference<P>::type... >*`